# Hibernate multiple attribute mappings same table deletion

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hopefully simple problem in Hibernate. I have Users and Projects. The users_projects (in my case user_project_association) has an extra attribute "role" to say if the user is project leader or normal user.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
private Set<UserProjectAssociation> userProjectAssociations = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_project_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "role_id=7")
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Set<User> projectLeaders = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_project_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

If i try to remove a project via "getEntityManager().remove(persistentInstance);" I can see in the log this sql statements:

```
Hibernate: 
/* delete collection com.XXX.core.model.Project.users */ delete 
    from
        user_project_role 
    where
        project_id=?
Hibernate: 
/* delete collection com.XXX.core.model.Project.projectLeaders */ delete 
    from
        user_project_role 
    where
        project_id=? 
        and (
            role_id=7
        ) 
Hibernate: 
/* delete com.XXX.core.model.UserProjectAssociation */ delete 
    from
        user_project_role 
    where
        id=?
```

and the error message:

```
2016-05-25 10:05:57 INFO  AbstractBatchImpl:208 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

and nothing is deleted. Does anyone have an idea to get my projects deleted?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puh. I found (the or a) solution for it. It's not really elegant, but it's working:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_project_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "role_id=7")
@SQLInsert(sql = "insert into user_project_role (project_id, user_id, role_id) values (?, ?, 7)")
@SQLDelete(sql = "delete from user_project_role where project_id=? and user_id=? and role_id = 7")
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Set<User> projectLeaders = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_project_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "role_id=8")
@SQLInsert(sql = "insert into user_project_role (project_id, user_id, role_id) values (?, ?, 8)")
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Set<User> projectUsers = new HashSet<>();
```

So I removed the userProjectAssociations attribute and added customized @SQLInsert and @SQLDelete Statements.

If I want to get all Users including normal users and project leaders I use this method:

```
public Set<User> getAllUsers() {
    Set<User> allUsers = new HashSet<>();
    allUsers.addAll(projectLeaders);
    allUsers.addAll(projectUsers);
    return allUsers;
}
```